# Hacked? Credit card fields showing under PayPal Express Checkout

Tags: magento, paypal, credit-card, magento-2.3, spree-paypal-express

I have noticed on our website that credit card fields are showing under the PayPal express checkout option but this wasn't the case before.

[Image of the checkout here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRxoY.png)

It didn't appear this way before and I've checked the backend of our Magento2 site to turn the fields off but there isn't an option for this.

I've disabled the checkout until I can figure it out.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is a standard Magento "Save Credit Card" payment method that looks exactly like that form, e.g. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252994/how-to-avoid-credit-card-number-validation-in-magento-2 -- there usually are radio buttons or similar to switch between the payment methods. Perhaps something about your site's theme suppresses their display. So, make sure you don't just have another payment method enabled in addition to PP EC. A hacker would probably make it look like a more legitimate option so that's not my first suspicion

Comment: Thanks for the help. The credit card fields are part of the PayPal express checkout configuration. If I disable PayPal express all the fields disappear but I can't see any options within the configuration that would allow this or an option to turn off.